# pdflayer API post request saying I didnt not provide api_key even though it did

Tags: javascript, api, post, axios

I am currently trying to work with the API from http://www.pdflayer.com, however I am having issues with providing the api_key through a post request with Axios.

My code looks like this:

```js
var config = require('./../config');
var axios = require('axios');
var fs = require('fs');

const BASE_URL = 'http://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert';

module.exports = {

    createQuotePdf() {
        var data = {
            document_url: 'https://www.apple.com',
            access_key: config.pdflayer_acccess_key,
            page_size: 'A4',
            test: '1'
         }

        axios.post(BASE_URL, data)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            fs.writeFile('./download.pdf', data.body, function(err) {
                if (err) console.log('error: ', err);
            })
        });
    }

};
```

However, every time I make the request, it is saying that I did not provide the api key, even though I specified.

It would be great if someone could help me.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

For anybody having the same issue, here is the working solution:

```js
var config = require('./../config');
var request = require('request');

var BASE_URL = 'http://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert';
var ACCESS_KEY = '?access_key=' + config.pdflayer_acccess_key;
var API_URL = BASE_URL + ACCESS_KEY;

module.exports = {

    createPdf() {

        var formData = {
            document_html: `<html><body>Hello World</body></html>`
        }

        request.post({url: API_URL, formData: formData, encoding: null}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
              // Here you can save the file or do anything else with it
                console.log(body);
            }
        });
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending it directly to your BASE_URL since that seams to be the way they are building it

`BASE_URL = ('http://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert?access_key=', YOUR_ACCES_KEY)'`

Comment: Yes I tried that and that also works, however in that case all other parameters that I provide through the post request are also not detected, so even if my api key would work, then I still have the same issue with the other parameters. That’s why i believe it’s the same underlying issue. And some parameters need to be provided via Post instead of appending them to the URL.

Comment: An example of a parameter that is only accessable through post is document_html

Comment: I see, will see if I can find a solution for it.